# apply function to all variables with string in name

Tags: r

Suppose you have 3 variables, namely

```
VAR1 = 3
VAR2 = 4
VAR3 = 2
```

Is there a way to transform all variables with the string 'VAR' in their name to, lets say, characters?

Comment: Probably. Is this really how you want to organize your data, though? If you're working with related items, you might want them in a list all together

Comment: Ah, yes, it might be better to put them in a list (for the project i'm working on atm). Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally one tries to group such variables in a list but if not then we can do this:

```
for(nm in ls(pattern = "^VAR")) .GlobalEnv[[nm]] <- as.character(.GlobalEnv[[nm]])
```

### Environment that is not the global environment

If you have these in an environment that is not the global environment then modify this as follows.  The first line of the function body defines the test data, the next line puts the current environment in a variable `e` for convenience and the line after that performs the transformations.  Finally we check what the variables have been transformed to.

```
f <- function() {
  VAR1 <- 1; VAR2 <- 2; VAR3 <- 3  # test data
  e <- environment()  # current environment
  for(nm in ls(pattern = "^VAR")) e[[nm]] <- as.character(e[[nm]])
  str(VAR1); str(VAR2); str(VAR3)  # check results 
}
f()
```

### List

If you can arrange that these are in a list instead then:

```
L <- list(VAR1 = 1, VAR2 = 2, VAR3 = 3) # test data
L <- lapply(L, as.character)
```

or if there are some elements that are not to be processed:

```
L2 <- list(VAR1 = 1, VAR2 = 2, VAR3 = 3, other = 4) # test data
ix <- grep("^VAR", names(L2))
L2[ix] <- lapply(L2[ix], as.character)
```

If you don't want to overwrite `L` and `L2` -- overwriting tends to make debugging more difficult -- then use `Lnew <- lapply(L, as.character)` and `L2new <- replace(L2, ix, lapply(L2[ix], as.character))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can search all `VAR` with `grep` and `ls` and then assign the new type in a loop.

```
VAR1 = 3
VAR2 = 4
VAR3 = 2
tt <- grep("^VAR", ls(), value = TRUE)
for(i in seq(tt)) assign(tt[i], as.character(get(tt[i])))
is.character(VAR1)
[1] TRUE
```

or shorter taking the loop from [@g-grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59411091/10488504).

```
for(i in ls(pattern = "^VAR")) assign(i, as.character(get(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transform numeric types to characters with the function "toString()"

```
VAR1 <- 3
class(VAR1)  # numeric

VAR1 <- toString(VAR1)
class(VAR1)  # character
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L <- data.frame(VAR1 = 1, VAR2 = 2, VAR3 = 4)
str(L)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ VAR1: num 1
$ VAR2: num 2
$ VAR3: num 4

l2<-lapply(L,toString)
str(l2)
List of 3
$ VAR1: chr "1"
$ VAR2: chr "2"
$ VAR3: chr "4"
```